# Execute a Command if Two Files Exist

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement

Im Trying to Execute a Command if Two Files Exist on a Location

If Only Either One of Two File Exist Script must Execute another different command 
here is the script i tried

if [ -e /Users/NJ/Library && /Users/NJ/Desktop ];then

echo both

else

echo single

fi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate the tests into their own square brackets:

```
if [ -e file ] && [ -e file ]; then
  echo "wow"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -e "/Users/NJ/Library" -a -e "/Users/NJ/Desktop" ];then
```

....

the `[ condition ]` evaluator uses -a for AND & -o for OR. [Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) is a manual.

OR use below syntax.

```
if [ -e "/Users/NJ/Library" ] && [ -e "/Users/NJ/Desktop" ];then
```

....

Comment: Oo Sorry Im Late Thanks anishsane :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double bracket insted of a simple :

```
if [[ -e /Users/NJ/Library && -e /Users/NJ/Desktop ]] ;then

echo both

else

echo single

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

if [ -e /Users/NJ/Library ] && [ -e /Users/NJ/Desktop ] ;then

echo both

else

echo single

fi

## This Pattern Works Good